# Problems using a js module is ts project

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a react ts project where I installed a pure js module: crypto-prices. Considering this module doesn't have any @types source, I created a `decs.d.ts` file with:

```
declare module "crypto-prices"
```

This removes the IDE issue. Yet, when I try to use the cryptoPrice modules through

```
import cryptoPrice from 'crypto-prices'
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't resolve 'crypto-prices' in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Import it like this,

```
import * as cryptoPrice from 'crypto-prices'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `decs.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json`. If `decs.d.ts` is in the same folder as `tsconfig.json` it should look something like below:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
        "./decs.d.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    }
}
```